# Thumbnails missing in Nautilus List View with Small Icons in 17.10

Tags: gnome, nautilus, icons

After upgrading to Ubuntu 17.10, I find it strange that Thumbnails are missing in Nautilus' List View. They work fine when I switch to the Icon View or enlarge the icon size (anything else but 'small' works).

I guess this is a new feature, but I can't find any resources on the Web addressing this.

Any way to enable the thumbnail display in List View with small icons?