# Nautilus does not show thumbnails anymore in list view 100% zoom

Tags: nautilus, 18.04, dconf, thumbnails

Since I upgraded to Bionic Beaver, I don't see the thumbnails in list view anymore when the zoom level is 100%. I must zoom to 150% to see them. How to change that back ? I did not find any obvious dconf settings...

**Update several years later**: according to the link provided by @MikeDacre below, this seems to be a GNOME issue that may be a design choice, and Ubuntu is not likely to tweak GNOME to revert this behaviour.

Comment: PS : I am aware that there is an open similar question here : https://askubuntu.com/questions/968320/thumbnails-missing-in-nautilus-list-view-with-small-icons-in-17-10 But in my case, I had no problem with Nautilus in Ubuntu 17.10, so it is not the same question.

Comment: Note that there is a bug filed for this here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1769358